# Consulta de formulacion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hola tengo una pequeña consulta, en una aplicacion rails, he visto mucho esto:

> args[:where] && args[:where][:establishment_id]

La consulta es que significan ambos dos, son argument hash de ruby? el segundo busca "donde el key es establishment_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumo que deben usarlo para que el código no falle en caso que `args[:where]` no esté presente.
Por ejemplo:

```
[1] pry(main)> args = { where: { establishment_id: 1 } }
=> {:where=>{:establishment_id=>1}}
[2] pry(main)> args[:where] && args[:where][:establishment_id]
=> 1
```

luego en caso de que en `args` no viniese definido `:where`, el código no se caería.

```
[3] pry(main)> args = {}
=> {}
[4] pry(main)> args[:where] && args[:where][:establishment_id]
=> nil
```

Dada la última definición de `args`, si accedes directamente a `:establishment_id` sin verificar que exista `:where`, tu código fallará:

```
[5] pry(main)> args = {}
=> {}
[6] pry(main)> args[:where][:establishment_id]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):5:in `<main>'
```

si lo que te molesta es ver tanto `args[:where] &&`, otra forma de lograr lo mismo es con [`.try`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/try):

```
[7] pry(main)> args = {}
=> {}
[8] pry(main)> args[:where].try(:[], :establishment_id)
=> nil
```

Y si estás usando ruby 2.3 o mayor, puedes usar [`.dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) y hacer tu código más simple aún:

```
[9] pry(main)> args = {}
=> {}
[10] pry(main)> args.dig(:where, :establishment_id)
=> nil
[11] pry(main)> args = { where: { establishment_id: 1 } }
=> {:where=>{:establishment_id=>1}}
[12] pry(main)> args.dig(:where, :establishment_id)
=> 1
```